# Best practice for remote notification of instant messaging app on the server side

Tags: ios, server, apple-push-notifications

Suppose there are 2 people A and B, they are chatting using my instance messaging app, A or B may switch to other app or lock screen when the peer sends a message. As you know, the message comes from A will first send to server, then the server will send it to B. If the app of B is not in foreground, it will not get the message instantly, so I should use remote notification.

What I want to know is how my server side to achieve the Remote Notification functionality. I have two option.

1. I send message to APNS every time when the server gets a message.
2. I keep the app status(foreground or background) of A and B, when a message comes in, if the peer is in foreground, don't send the notification to APNS, otherwise send the notification.

The first one is a easy way but it may increase the pressure of APNS server.

The second one is complicated, it must keep the app status for every user and it may be not accurate. Suppose when the app of "A" comes to background and the network is very bad then, "A" fails to notify the server that it goes into background, the server consider that "A" is in foreground, so when "B" sends a message to "A", server won't send a remote notification to APNS.

Anyone who has experience on that please share your solution, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I send message to APNS every time when the server gets a message.

Exactly! Just send a push notification for each message. If the app is in foreground, the notification won't be displayed anyways.

> The first one is a easy way but it may increase the pressure of APNS
>   server.

APNS will be able to handle it, don't worry about that.

If you try to synchronize the app state with the server, you will sooner or later run into race conditions and other problems, so don't make things more complicated than necessary...

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm still not sure of the feasibility of this strategy. I wonder if whatsapp or wechat is using this strategy.

Comment: From my experience I can tell you that you won't have any problems with this. Moreover, even if WhatsApp is not pushing every single message, they are probably sending more push notifications every day than you will do in near future, so APNS can handle that...

Answer (score 0):

Although Push(remote) Notifications are delivered almost instantaneously (APNS is scaled to take load), I would suggest you to explore third part libraries. Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) on this. It would be worth exploring [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework). [This](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2013-07-30-building-an-ios-group-messenger-app/) may also be useful.

Comment: I'm sorry that you're telling how to build a instant messaging app, but what I want to know is how to build a Push notification server and which strategy should I use to notice the user whose app is in the background.

Comment: You should go with APNS based push notifications as they get delivered even in background.

Comment: And I replied on same line... do you see some disconnect?